# Running an Ajax click event on a div added by another Ajax click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

For some reason I can't run the Ajax click on a div that was just added by another ajax click event on the exact same page.

Both ajax requests use the same request page, but contain a different data string.

**These are my two Ajax functions**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#log_login').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email=$("#log_email").val();
        var login=$("#log_login").html();
        var dataString = 'email='+email+'&login='+login;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '$language_rewrite/$administrator_login/forgotpassword',
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#login-msg").hide();
                $("#log_login").html('$translate_login_8...');
            },
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                    if(html.indexOf("$forgot_translate_1") > -1){
                        $("#p_log_email").html('$forgot_translate_1');
                        $("#log_verify_code").html('<input id="log_code" type="text" name="email" placeholder="$admin_f_subject"/><br>');
                        $("#log_verify_btn").html('<div id="log_verify" name="login" class="standard-button">$admin_verify_btn</div>');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#log_verify').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var code = $("#log_code").val();
        var verify = $("#log_verify").html();
        var dataStringTwo = 'code='+code+'&verify='+verify;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '$language_rewrite/$administrator_login/forgotpassword',
            data: dataStringTwo,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#login-msg").hide();
                $("#log_verify").html('$admin_verify_btn...');
            },
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                    if(html.indexOf("1") > -1){
                        $("#log-verify").html('<div id="log_login2" name="login" class="standard-button">FINISHED</div>');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**This is the HTML code that is being changed**

```
<div id="log_verify_code">
    <input id="log_email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $translate_login_2; ?>"/><br>
        <input id="log_code" type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
<div id="log_verify_btn">
    <div id="log_login" name="login" class="standard-button"><?php echo $translate_login_8; ?></div>
    <input id="log_verify" type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
```

The first Ajax functions works perfectly, and it changes the input field, however when I press the second button nothing happens. Not even an error, or a PHP error. Nothing. How come?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't attempting to bind an event listener to an object that doesn't yet exist at the time of binding?

Comment: So the Ajax code binds itself upon load? It won't "rebind" itself whenever the item appears on the page?

Comment: No. If you break down exactly what the code does, it finds every element with the id "log_verify" at load time, of which there are none (although a bit confusingly you have one called "log-verify") and binds to them but since there are none it binds to nothing. One option is binding to the document body and filtering to only events on the element you are interested in. JQuery has built in support for this. See the documentation for [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @Chris I updated my code, there shouldn't be anything that makes the code not work now, should it? I added a hidden input element so that it binds to the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to existing elements. For future elements you must use delegated events and bind to existing ancestor, or for instance the document itself.

```
$(document).on("click", ".future-elem", function() {
  // code here
});
```

Source: [$.on - read: direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

EDIT: just saw this was already being commented

Comment: Worked perfectly! Why doesn't binding to a hidden element that is being changed/removed and re-added work?

Comment: because removing also removes (destroys) the handler(s)

Comment: I think when you use .html it will remove the html then replace it with the new html